How to install and give permission for docker in shell script
I try install docker like this on EC2 amazon linux and I found this error
# Install Docker
sudo yum install -y docker
sudo systemctl enable docker
sudo systemctl start docker
sudo usermod -aG docker ec2-user

permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get "http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.44/containers/json": dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
It can fix by control+C and ssh to instance again but I don't want that method how can I completed one time in shellscript and make it can run without control+C and ssh again

See Reload a Linux user's group assignments without logging out

If you're able to use sudo to this extent, use it to run docker commands too.  Since you can all but trivially docker run -v /:/host a container that takes over the host system, it's appropriate to require root permissions to use it.
